# How to fix the carousel image sliding from end of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

When the carousel image is sliding to left it was showing that the image is sliding from the end of the screen. I want to slide the image from the end of the div. I used the bootstrap carousel image. It was working before but when I make it to move only right it was moving from end of the page. Please fix that.

**Html code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
.carousel-indicators{


}
.carousel-inner{
position: relative;
width: 911px;
overflow: hidden;
left: 121px;

}
h2{
font-size: 18px;
top: -20px;
position: relative;
background: #0baadb;
height: 22px;
width: 67%;
left: 17%;

}
ol, ul{
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.carousel.vertical {
    position: relative;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
p{
line-height: 1.1;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item {
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    top: 0;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item div {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 80px;
    line-height: 300px;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .prev,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .right {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
    top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .prev.right,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .active {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    top: 0;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .active.right,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .active.left {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    top: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel vertical slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators" >
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <p class="slider">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa voluptatibus,<br><br>quas ad dolorum, recusandae consectetur. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit
                        amet <br>est impedit culpa dignissimos laudantium
                        deleniti, dicta exercitationem sit
                        <br> consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, autem iste. Soluta quas quisquam 
                       <br>reiciendis vero quod, corrupti dolorum magnam culpa
                        corporis <br>deserunt quibusdam.
                        Incidunt eveniet unde, ratione rem at error accusantium!</p>
                    <img src="Images/1.jpg" class="slider_image">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <p class="slider">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa voluptatibus,<br><br>quas ad dolorum, recusandae consectetur. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit
                        amet <br>est impedit culpa dignissimos laudantium
                        deleniti, dicta exercitationem sit
                        <br> consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, autem iste. Soluta quas quisquam 
                       <br>reiciendis vero quod, corrupti dolorum magnam culpa
                        corporis <br>deserunt quibusdam.
                        Incidunt eveniet unde, ratione rem at error accusantium!</p>
                    <img src="Images/1.jpg" style="width:100%;" class="slider_image">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <p class="slider">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa voluptatibus,<br><br>quas ad dolorum, recusandae consectetur. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit
                        amet <br>est impedit culpa dignissimos laudantium
                        deleniti, dicta exercitationem sit
                        <br> consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, autem iste. Soluta quas quisquam 
                       <br>reiciendis vero quod, corrupti dolorum magnam culpa
                        corporis <br>deserunt quibusdam.
                        Incidunt eveniet unde, ratione rem at error accusantium!</p>
                    <img src="Images/1.jpg" style="width:100%;" class="slider_image">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <p class="slider">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa voluptatibus,<br><br>quas ad dolorum, recusandae consectetur. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit
                        amet <br>est impedit culpa dignissimos laudantium
                        deleniti, dicta exercitationem sit
                        <br> consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, autem iste. Soluta quas quisquam 
                       <br>reiciendis vero quod, corrupti dolorum magnam culpa
                        corporis <br>deserunt quibusdam.
                        Incidunt eveniet unde, ratione rem at error accusantium!</p>
                    <img src="Images/1.jpg" style="width:100%;" class="slider_image">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <p class="slider">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa voluptatibus,<br><br>quas ad dolorum, recusandae consectetur. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit
                        amet <br>est impedit culpa dignissimos laudantium
                        deleniti, dicta exercitationem sit
                        <br> consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, autem iste. Soluta quas quisquam 
                       <br>reiciendis vero quod, corrupti dolorum magnam culpa
                        corporis <br>deserunt quibusdam.
                        Incidunt eveniet unde, ratione rem at error accusantium!</p>
                    <img src="Images/1.jpg" style="width:100%;" class="slider_image">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

**css code**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.slider {
margin: 0 0 -187px !important;
background: #6c6cf7 !important;
position: relative !important;
height: 258px !important;
padding: 54px !important;
}

.slider_image {
width: 31% !important;
position: relative !important;
top: -24px !important;
left: 599px !important;
}

.carousel-indicators li {
    display: inline-block !important;
    text-indent: -999px!important;
    cursor: pointer!important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important;
    border: 1px solid #fff!important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
    position: relative!important;
left: -355px !important;
top: -5px !important;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    width: 11px!important;
    height: 11px!important;
}
.carousel.vertical {
    position: relative !important;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%!important;
    width: auto!important;
}
.carousel.vertical {
    position: relative !important;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: auto !important;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item {
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out!important;
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) !important;
    top: 0!important;
    background: #ccc!important;
    width: 80% !important;
    height: 260px !important;
    border: 1px solid #e6e6e6 !important;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .item div {
    text-align: center !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    font-size: 80px !important;
    line-height: 300px !important;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .prev,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .right {
    transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0) !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .prev.right,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .next.left,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .active {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .active.right,
.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner > .active.left {
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0) !important;
    top: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: What kind of images are you using (Square, Rectangle)? Do they fit? It would be best to replace the relative path in your question with URLs.

Comment: What you posted is not sufficient to create a [mcve] and, without one, the result of your code cannot be inspected. This means that, in current form, your question cannot be answered and is therefore *off-topic* here, because it has 0 chances of being useful to anyone, including yourself. Please create a *runnable* [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Souvik I am also fairly new on stack overflow but I do have experience using carousels.

It is not yet responsive so I would take a look at it in this code-pen I made instead: [link to codepen](https://codepen.io/jrod95/pen/VwWLVqx)

Please inspect the code below:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


.slider {
margin: 0 0 -187px !important;
background: #6c6cf7 !important;
position: relative !important;
height: 350px !important;
padding: 54px !important;
}

.slider_image {
  width:  200px !important;
  height: 200px !important;
  position: relative !important;
  top: -85px !important;
  left: 600px !important;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.slide-buttons li {
    display: inline-block !important;
    text-indent: -999px!important;
    cursor: pointer!important;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)!important;
    border: 1px solid #fff!important;
    border-radius: 4px !important;
    position: relative!important;
    left: -355px !important;
    top: -5px !important;
}

.carousel-indicators .active {
    width: 11px!important;
    height: 11px!important;
}
.carousel .vertical {
    position: relative !important;
}

.carousel .vertical .carousel-inner {
    height: 100%!important;
    width: auto!important;
}
.carousel.vertical {
    position: relative !important;
}

.carousel.vertical .carousel-inner {
    height: 100% !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style2.css">
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/script2.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel vertical slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
            <ol class="carousel-indicators slide-buttons" >
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <p class="slider">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa voluptatibus,<br><br>quas ad dolorum, recusandae consectetur. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit
                        amet <br>est impedit culpa dignissimos laudantium
                        deleniti, dicta exercitationem sit
                        <br> consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, autem iste. Soluta quas quisquam 
                       <br>reiciendis vero quod, corrupti dolorum magnam culpa
                        corporis <br>deserunt quibusdam.
                        Incidunt eveniet unde, ratione rem at error accusantium!</p>
                    <img src="https://s2.glbimg.com/zA1FFp9GyQ0w2XPA_8ChslCnqWI=/512x320/smart/e.glbimg.com/og/ed/f/original/2020/03/27/jure-tovrljan-coronavirus-logos-grey_dezeen_2364_col_8.jpg" class="slider_image">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <p class="slider">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa voluptatibus,<br><br>quas ad dolorum, recusandae consectetur. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit
                        amet <br>est impedit culpa dignissimos laudantium
                        deleniti, dicta exercitationem sit
                        <br> consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, autem iste. Soluta quas quisquam 
                       <br>reiciendis vero quod, corrupti dolorum magnam culpa
                        corporis <br>deserunt quibusdam.
                        Incidunt eveniet unde, ratione rem at error accusantium!</p>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSPHRvtFUvNT9Rrpz2HE4gu05hPPg8m7DweCg&usqp=CAU" style="width:100%;" class="slider_image">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <p class="slider">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa voluptatibus,<br><br>quas ad dolorum, recusandae consectetur. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit
                        amet <br>est impedit culpa dignissimos laudantium
                        deleniti, dicta exercitationem sit
                        <br> consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, autem iste. Soluta quas quisquam 
                       <br>reiciendis vero quod, corrupti dolorum magnam culpa
                        corporis <br>deserunt quibusdam.
                        Incidunt eveniet unde, ratione rem at error accusantium!</p>
                    <img src="https://visionpublicidade.com.br/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/logos.png" style="width:100%;" class="slider_image">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <p class="slider">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa voluptatibus,<br><br>quas ad dolorum, recusandae consectetur. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit
                        amet <br>est impedit culpa dignissimos laudantium
                        deleniti, dicta exercitationem sit
                        <br> consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, autem iste. Soluta quas quisquam 
                       <br>reiciendis vero quod, corrupti dolorum magnam culpa
                        corporis <br>deserunt quibusdam.
                        Incidunt eveniet unde, ratione rem at error accusantium!</p>
                    <img src="https://s2.glbimg.com/fezRS3aZpA7zoqcgwiM7MQUSHek=/620x455/e.glbimg.com/og/ed/f/original/2020/03/27/jure-tovrljan-coronavirus-logos-grey_dezeen_2364_col_6.jpg" style="width:100%;" class="slider_image">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <p class="slider">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa voluptatibus,<br><br>quas ad dolorum, recusandae consectetur. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit
                        amet <br>est impedit culpa dignissimos laudantium
                        deleniti, dicta exercitationem sit
                        <br> consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus, autem iste. Soluta quas quisquam 
                       <br>reiciendis vero quod, corrupti dolorum magnam culpa
                        corporis <br>deserunt quibusdam.
                        Incidunt eveniet unde, ratione rem at error accusantium!</p>
                    <img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/shopifycloud/hatchful_web_two/bundles/4a14e7b2de7f6eaf5a6c98cb8c00b8de.png" style="width:100%;" class="slider_image">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
      
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I got rid of all of the transformations you had in CSS which were simply not working and conflicting with each other and left the standard Bootstrap carousel animation features. I also removed the styles from the HTML. Try to keep CSS and HTML separate to have cleaner more readable code.

From here I would recommend you do the following:
1.) Position the buttons correctly
2.) Position your images in the right place and size them to your liking.
3.) Make your project responsive using media queries if this is something you are interested in. See the following link:

> [Link to BootStrap Media Queries Documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/)

4.) Review the following documentation on using CSS transforms if there is something you want to change regarding the slide transitioning:
[Using CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transforms/Using_CSS_transforms)

5.) Use the browser and the google chrome console to test your changes if you are not doing so already.

Let me know how it goes, best of luck!